# What is the cost per hour of a Gulfstream V?

Tags: cost, gulfstream

Could someone inform me about the exact operational costs of a flight hour for this specific type of aircraft?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Gulfstream G550](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulfstream_G550) is a variant of the Gulfstream V.

From [aopa.org](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2015/november/16/hourly-operating-costs-of-45-jets-compared) (November 16, 2015) for the G550, it costs $4,731.05 per hour, give or take. (Assuming the plane is paid for already.)

Adjusted for [inflation](http://data.bls.gov/cgi-bin/cpicalc.pl) that's **$4,825.11.**

Note that the GV is older than the G550, and would generally cost more to operate.

> This figure includes fuel, maintenance (parts and labor), engine reserves, auxiliary power units if applicable, and miscellaneous expenses to include crew travel, catering and cabin supplies, landing and parking fees—all boiled down to a single number.

Comment: Does that include payments on the aircraft, or assume it's paid for?

Comment: Well there's another dream shattered!

Comment: Damn, almost thought it would be affordable.

Comment: Depends on the number of flight hours you log a year.  Before reading your answer I would have guessed $5,000/flight hour.  So your answer sounds about right.  Lotta money.

Comment: That why they HATE AOGs

Comment: Note that G-V's are older than the G550's and generally cost more to operate because of that....

Comment: I'd blow that dough for an hour in a G550, but in the right seat, not the cabin. :)